# Rails routing, not a supported controller name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am in the process of learning Rails, I am trying to make a small search functionality, I am setting up the route for this like this:

```
get 'search?q=:keyword' => 'search?q=#show'
```

and in the url I am trying to access this using

```
http://localhost:3000/search?q=test
```

but this is giving me this error: not a supported controller name.

Youssef

Comment: My advice for you is to read some guides about routing. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are trying to route with the query string `?=` still in the path. [Rails is a little smarter than that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string) so the parameters will be passed automatically.

```
get 'search' => 'search#show'
```

Will retain the parameters in the redirect without you needing to do anything extra.